# Having a hard time understanding file locations on Mac in R

Tags: r

So I'm following a tutorial on making a word cloud with R. This is the first time getting back into programming for me in a long time and Im having issues with file directories and file locations to start.

```
   > cname <- file.path(".","corpus","target")
   > library (tm)
   > docs <- Corpus(DirSource(cname))
   Error in DirSource(cname) : empty directory
```

I placed the file at the Mac root drive and assumed thats what that location meant (/corpus/target) but it reads that its not being found.

This is the tutorial in question - http://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2014/05/build-word-cloud-text-mining-tools/?utm_source=Linkedinstatus&utm_medium=Social&utm_campaign=070514

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What happens when you do `list.files(file.path(".", "corpus", "target"))`?

Comment: Then there's nothing in that directory

Comment: Thx - Janos below pointed out the same and i realized my silly error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the first parameter to empty string:

```
cname <- file.path("", "corpus", "target")
```

This will correctly give the absolute path from the filesystem root, `/corpus/target` on a Mac.

After that, confirm that you have the right directory with:

```
list.files(cname)
```

Comment: I still get character(0)

Comment: > cname <- file.path("", "corpus", "target")
> list.files(cname)
character(0)

Comment: Are there really any files in `/corpus/target` ?

Comment: Am embarrassed, but your question did the trick.  The file name was "target" .. and i now realize the cname was looking for subdirectory named "target" ... thx a ton.